# Is g@ useful outside of VimL scripting, i.e. when editing? (Instead of vim-repeat)

Tags: operator-pending-mode

I read on an old none commentable reddit that Tpope no longer uses his [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) plugin, and instead uses `g@`. I have used `g@` in plugins, and unstand you set `opfunc` first, then `g@{motion}` will run `opfunc` on the motion.

I have had some success using `g@` when editing to repeat a titlecase function, but havent figured out how to repeat for example `vim-surround` functionality with it. Does anyone find it useful when editing text (i.e. outside the context of vim scripting).

Comment: I can't really answer your question, however I think you used `@g` instead of `g@` in the title and the first sentence of your question and if I understand properly that is a typo (which would be worth editing to avoid confusion). Could you also link the Reddit post you are referring to just for my curiosity please?

Comment: Also FWIW vim surround [still seems to be using vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/master/plugin/surround.vim#L477) and his dotfiles [still references](https://github.com/tpope/tpope/blob/master/.vim/after/plugin/surround.vim) the surround plugin code.

Comment: @statox Fixed it thank you. I google the post but can't find it. It was a few months ago, but made a note to return to research.

Comment: [If this is his plugins that hes using](https://github.com/tpope/tpope/tree/master/.vim/after/plugin) I don't see vim-repeat there. Leaving support in vim-surround for vim-repeat is different to not using vim-repeat.

Comment: You are completely right about this last comment. I might have been a bit too fast to conclude that he still uses repeat, my bad :)

Comment: 1. He still uses [`vim-repeat`](https://github.com/tpope/tpope/blob/master/.vim/after/autoload/repeat.vim) for old scripts.  2. He tries to avoid the plugin for future scripts [in favor of opfuncs](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat/issues/63#issuecomment-390281441) (and he may refactor some old code to get rid of it).  3. He's right; the plugin has bugs, which native repetition can fix.

Comment: @user938271 I've always been to lazy to figure this out, but is this implementation difference the reason that [vim-operator-surround](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-operator-surround) exists (or at least, an advantage it has over surround.vim)?

Comment: @Rich I guess it's one of the reasons why the plugin exists, yes.  It doesn't need vim-repeat to be repeatable, but it seems to rely on [`vim-operator-user`](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user) to install the operator mappings.  [`vim-sandwich`](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) is another alternative, which afaict doesn't have any dependency.

Answer (score 4):

`g@` is extremely useful for plugins and custom maps, but it's not so useful by itself.

One reason is that `opfunc`, which is a global option, needs to be set correctly before you type `g@`.  Theoretically, you could use `:set opfunc=MyFunc` followed by `g@` but you may as well create a mapping wrapper which does `:set opfunc=myFunc<cr>g@` since then it works regardless of what `opfunc` was set to before.

---

Generally, a plugin which adds operators should use `g@` so that repeating with `.` works.
Likewise, a plugin which adds "whole operations" should support repeating by using `g@l` or similar.

Since plugins should be designed to allow repeating via `.`, there is no need to use `g@`.  It is unlikely that you can repeat a plugin's map via `g@` unless it was designed specifically to allow that.  But in that case, the plugin would likely be designed to support `.` repeating.

Comment: "Since plugins should be designed to allow repeating via ." ... although I have found this is mostly not the case, I guess that is why vim-repeat exists in the first case? I think if you can repeat it with g@, then one might as well just use . instead, which means g@ is not very beneficial for editing use as you state.

Comment: Well, `vim-repeat` exists from a time long ago.  I don't know of a case where `g@` won't work but `vim-repeat` will (but might be wrong).  The one advantage it still has is the interface is a bit nicer for plugins to use.