# Repeat surroundings commands with dot

Tags: plugin-vim-surround

I'm using `kana/vim-surround` plugin to change/delete the surroundings of a word.
How can I use the dot to repeat some command from this plugin?
For example, the word `"pineapple"` becomes `_pineapple_` after typing `cs"_`.
The whole point of me using this plugin was to improve parsing speed of some objects, the dot mechanism would be essential.

Comment: Get vim-repeat from same author (tpope/vim-repeat....looks like u are using a fork...any particular reason?)

Comment: Wow, so perfect.. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the original vim-surround plug-in is the one by tpope. The one you're getting is one that was modified by kana (according to the comments at the top of the plug-in script), but the latest commits in that repo are from 2010, over ten years ago... I'd suggest you should switch to `tpope/vim-surround`, which is definitely a maintained plug-in.

Comment: @BLayer Please post that as an answer, since it clearly solved the OP's issue. Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden I searched for the plugin in [Vim Awesome](https://vimawesome.com/) and installed tpope's package. I did noticed that the author was different but kept the installation. Good to know that! Thanks

Comment: @BLayer Sounds good, thanks!

Comment: @BLayer For some context on ensuring our questions have posted answers: https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1525/18609 we're slightly below 90% in answered questions. (There's also the average answers per question, even though I'm somewhat skeptical about that particular metric.) Cheers!

Comment: @filbranden Those numbers always seem odd to me, e.g. two categories crushed and three, meh. It's too bad there's not a category about # votes per answer. I think we lag there which could dampen some posters' enthusiasm. (I have some evidence of low votes/answer based on a few reports but haven't done a deep dive on it.)

Comment: Btw @BLayer , no particular reason for having installed this fork, just didn't know the original author at first. Gonna install tpope's version!

Comment: Done! I usually don't upvote accepted answers due to discussions I've red in the Meta, but the vote is mine and your answer is great hahah also, I've looked into it and this fork doesn't seem to have any special existence reason.

Comment: @Teodoro Really? Do you have that Meta link? I've not heard of that notion before. Anyways, much appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: Very weird, I swear I've red a post were an answer with hundreds of upvotes stated that upvoting the answer you accepted was a bad practice. But now I just find posts saying the opposite!  
Good to know, I'm going to review my old acceptances hahhaha

Comment: Heh. Whoops. That definitely didn't sound like a convention I'd heard of before. Ah well...**** happens. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, this doesn't appear to have been answered before given how easy of an answer it is...

The author of vim-surround, Tim Pope, wrote another plugin specifically to address the issue of `.` (dot-repeat) not working cleanly with operations in a couple of his plugins including vim-surround.

It is [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat)

(FYI, the other supported plugins are speeddating, unimpaired, vim-easyclip and vim-radical as listed in the README. )

As an aside, there might have been thoughts of more plugins being made compatible with vim-repeat but for whatever reason the available list is small. One reason may be because of the native functionality that can be used in a solution. For the curious:
[Is g@ useful outside of VimL scripting, i.e. when editing? (Instead of vim-repeat)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/is-g-useful-outside-of-viml-scripting-i-e-when-editing-instead-of-vim-repea)

I'm guessing, though, that OP is looking for a low friction solution and vim-repeat is greased lightning in this case. (I personally use it with vim-surround as of late and it's worked well for me.)

*Okay, I think I've sufficiently padded this answer that started out as a six word comment and whose length made me reluctant to post this.* ;)